# What needs to be done to downgrade a ESRI addin from 10.1 to 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects, add-in

I have created an esri addin which targeted ArcGIS 10.1, however I need to have the addin to work on ArcGIS 10, what needs to be done within my solution to get it working? 
I have checked the references, I have changed the targeted version witihin the config.xml, but when I try and run the addin (from Debug mode in VS2010) I don't see the addin as I would on the 10.1 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you must re-compile the addin on a development machine that is running 10